# Chapter 1: Does the same Character save you at the end?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

At the end of the first chapter, after Larry punched me down, my Lee was saved by Kenny stating that he would not leave a good friend behind.

Depending on my past actions, will it always be Kenny who saves me or does only the way he addresses me change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what decisions you made previously, Kenny will always be there to rescue you.

The only thing that changes is what Kenny will say as he's rescuing you. If you are not in such a good standing with him, he will say something along the line of: even if you have been a jerk to him, he'd still rescue you.